# How to use react-pdf annotation?

Tags: pdf, annotations, pdf-annotations, react-pdf-viewer, react-pdfrenderer

I am loading pdf by react-pdf. I have two buttons Title and Author. When the user clicks on the title button, the background of the title will change, then click on the author, and it will change all author's name background colors of the pdf document.
How can I achieve this feature using react-pdf or any other react library for pdf? I have not found proper documentation on this topic - annotation based on user events.
Screenshot: https://paste.pics/2c8a9c449e86375c69624f62edad733c

Comment: I am using this library to load pdf in react https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf